# Delete all the memory allocated to an object

Tags: c++, oop, memory-leaks

I am writing a program which creates thousands of instances of a class that I borrowed from somebody else's code. For example I have a class `B`,

```
class B {
  B(int a);
  int some_function();
  ...
};
```

In my program, I create objects of this class:

```
int main() {
  for(int i=0; i<10000; i++) {
    B *b = new B(i);
    b->some_function();
    delete(b);
  }
}
```

But class `B` has memory leak and fills my RAM after a few iterations. Is there any way to remove all the memory allocated to this class after each iteration of my program?

P.S. the class is way more complicated than this example, so I have considered this option prior to debugging that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the class B inherit from some other class and destructor is not virtual. Can you check it out?

EDIT:

To check out leaks i recommand to install **valgrind** (software).

How install? in ubuntu, **sudo apt-get install valgrind**

How use it? Simply launch your program with it : **valgrind ./yourProgram**

How use it for leaks detections? **valgrind --leak-check=yes ./yourProgram**

[Here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) is a guide

Comment: class `B` is not inheriting from any other class but, inside this class (among attributes) there are abstract classes. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes I used valgrind to find out the memory leak but it is not telling me where is it. I will check the classes inside this class.

Comment: Compile your program with -g flag

Comment: Yesss, one of the classes inside this class `B` was inheriting but not having a virtual destructor. I did not know this point.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't. You'll have to fix that class.